# Azure CDN custom domain for http redirects to .azurewebsites.net

Tags: azure, dns, cname

I deployed my Umbraco 8 website to an Azure app service, created a CDN for the app service and configured the custom domain for the CDN.

[image]

In my domain provider (OVH) I added a CNAME for my domain so the Azure CDN could pass the verification.
[image]

My problem is that if go to a browser and type "https://www.culturaenvivo.com" everything works as expected. But if I type "www.culturaenvivo.com" the URL changes to the app service (cev.azurewebsites.net).

My CDN Origin configuration has both protocols configured.
[image]

What am I missing? Why is the URL changing to azurewebsites.net?

UPDATE: I added a rule engine in my Azure CDN to redirect from http to https but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: I just tried to input `www.culturaenvivo.com` at the address in a browser. It worked and redirect to `https://www.culturaenvivo.com`, so does this issue fix on your side now?

Comment: If you try http ://www.culturaenvivo.com you can see it sends you to https ://cev.azurewebsites.net/, which is my azure app service.
Note: Sorry for the extra whitespace in http but Stackoverflow formats the URL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It redirects from http to https now.

I added a .htacces file to my root folder with the following content

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.culturaenvivo.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried and found that the HTTP redirect to HTTPS worked. When I input the `http://www.culturaenvivo.com` in the browser address bar, it always
redirect to `https://www.culturaenvivo.com`.

[image: www.culturaenvivo.com]

If this is what you expect in your browser, you could try to new inPrivate windows to open your websites or clear the browser cache or clear DNS cache or restart your machine to see if it helps.

To configure Azure CDN HTTP-HTTPS redirection, you could read [this blog](https://medium.com/azure-architects/configuring-azure-cdn-http-https-redirection-2a9e4aab0a77). For example, if you are using the Standard Microsoft CDN price tier, you can simply add a new rule as follows on the Azure portal.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time, Nancy.

I tried with incognito mode and it works for http:// www.culturaenvivo.com but if you type culturaenvivo.com or http:// culturaenvivo.com if shows an error:
"Our services aren't available right now
We're working to restore all services as soon as possible. Please check back soon."

Comment: do you select http and https in your cdn origin ？

Comment: I updated my post with a screenshot but yes, I have both protocols selected.

Comment: Do you add the custom domain `culturaenvivo.com` in your CDN endpoint?

Comment: I've tried but I need to create a CNAME entry in my domain provider to validate my CDN custom domain. And apparently I cannot create a CNAME entry called "culturaenvivo.com" because "A CNAME RR for a root record is not allowed".

Comment: azure dns allow you to add alias record for root domain. You can search it online. I just send comment in my phone.

Comment: This helped me to create a CDN custom domain to my root domain
https://arlanblogs.alvarnet.com/adding-a-root-domain-to-azure-cdn-endpoint/

Comment: Yes, you can make it. So does this issue fix on your side? Is my reply helpful for you?

Comment: Yes, it was. Everything is working as expected now.